# Electron-forge: How to set entrypoint to url instead of static html file

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I used electron-forge webpack-typescript template to generate electron project.

By default it loads `index.html` as configured in `entryPoints` in `package.json`

```
...
"plugins": [
  [
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
    {
      "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
      "renderer": {
        "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
        "entryPoints": [
          {
            "name": "main_window",
            "html": "./src/index.html", // <-- HERE
            "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
]
...
```

I want to load angular url `http://localhost:4200` as the entry point.

When I change to `"html": "http://localhost:4200",`, it doesn't work.

I tried to remove the line from `package.json` and hard-coded the url in `index.ts`

```
...
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:4200");
...
```

this also doesn't work. How can I set entry to url instead of static HTML file?

Answer (score 2):

just make the entry point blank html with redirection

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com" />
<title>Page Moved</title>
</head><body>
<a href="http://www.example.com">continue</a></body>
</html>
```

advantage to this is, you can even add small javascript to first check if the target is available, to optionally display error message etc, if target port for some reason would not be available for app etc, or display simple splahh before app opens

Comment: thank you, I shifted to electron builder decades ago , but this seems to be a brilliant answer, however I don't have time to test it now (may be later), nor enough reputation to upvote you, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is electron-forge webpack template is expecting a `js,ts,html` files as mentioned in the project setup [documentation](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack), so you cannot set a server URL as a renderer there.

But what you can do is load your Angular webapp from your Electron main process. Actually as I did here on my [electron-angular-quick-start](https://github.com/sourcygen/electron-angular-quick-start/blob/master/workspaces/electron-app/main/components/window.ts#:%7E:text=private-,loadRenderer,-()%3A%20void%20%7B), you just have to check your config `dev or prod for example` and choose which resource `localhost:4200/index.html` you want to load.

```
private loadRenderer(): void {
    if (process.env.X_NODE_ENV === "development") {
      // Dev mode, take advantage of the live reload by loading local URL
      this.window.loadURL(`http://localhost:4200`);
    } else {
      // Else mode, we simply load angular bundle
      const indexPath = url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/angular_window/index.html`),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
      });
      this.window.loadURL(indexPath);
    }
}
```

If you are still interested in building apps with Electron and Angular, I suggest you have a look to understand how the starter works. Feel free to post any question or submit an issue on Github too.

Comment: thank you, I shifted to electron builder long time ago, and I don't have time to test it now (may be later), not enough reputation to upvote you, thanks again.